# Cardiac events/Myocardial infarction from 1 clinic or 1 large city daily data

Tags: statistics, cardiology, heart, heart-attack, myocardial-infarction

Requesting help in finding a DAILY data about cardiac events/myocardial infarction from 1 clinic or 1 large city, i.e. day by day number of events for at least a month.

It is very easy to find this stat for year(s) by months, but day by day, almost impossible, spent 3 days and have found only a few papers, related to the topic. So I'm curious, if there is a good source for this kind of data, any clinic(hospital)/city with good data will be much appreaciated!